# Converting to a common date format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, c#-4.0

I am trying to insert CSV data into SQL.

It has date column in the format "[image]"

You can see space before starting date and I cannot change it as this csv is protected using Azure services.

I am getting this error shown below:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store
> <7/20/2021 6:16> in Last Seen Column.  The expected type is DateTime.

I have done a logic to convert existing data formats as below

```
if (IsValidDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString()))
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(csvTable.Rows[i][Computer].ToString()
                       , csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen]);

                    }
                    else if (IsValidDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss", csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString()))
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(csvTable.Rows[i][Computer].ToString()
                                          , DateTime.ParseExact(csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString() + ",531", "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());


                    }
                    else if (IsValidDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy h:mm", csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString()))
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(csvTable.Rows[i][Computer].ToString()
                       , csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen]);

                    }
```

But every day new date formats are coming in csv so that I need to change the code each time a new date format comes.

Question 1:
Is there an easy way to make a common code for any date format instead of changing code for each date format?

Question 2: Since there is a space, I am getting the error, is there anyway I can trim the date?

> The funny thing is I am able to import the data without any issues in
> windows10 laptop using visual studio, but the error which I have given
> above is only appears when I run the same deployed exe through windows
> scheduler in the Windows server 2012 machine

Comment: If your data provider is giving you CSV files with variable date formats then you should take it up with them and ask them to ensure they provide the datetimes in a standard, consistent format

Comment: Secondly, I'd consider parsing the text into a `DateTime` using `TryParse`, or `TryParseExact` before adding it to your table row.  That way, you'd guarantee it was a recognised `DateTime` format (because it would already be one) rather than relying on the text being parsed correctly by your database

Comment: but still, is there any way that we can use code to convert any date format to a common format and insert into table?

Comment: the insert step should be done by sending it as a `DateTime` value, not a `string` - then there's no ambiguity; so that just leaves the parse step, which is as per the above

Comment: i am already doing it right? DateTime.ParseExact(csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString() + ",531", "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());

Comment: When you say "_any date format_" what does that mean?  How about `Tuesday 27th July 2021 2:5:53.1234` or `Tue 27 July 2021 14:05:53` or `2021-07-27T14:05:53.1234Z`.  There's so many ways to present a date that the concept of converting _any date_ seems unachievable

Comment: ok , i thought there should be  a code to change any format to universal format , then universal format to whatever format we like

Comment: @SmartestVEGA "any format" - sure: 04/05/03 - what date is that? think carefully

Comment: Ohhhh ok ...Got you, so that's not possible!

Comment: `every day new date formats are coming in excel` are you sure? Dates in Excel are stored physically as a `double` and displayed as text based on the cell's style. You convert that `double` to a `DateTime` with `DateTime.FromOADate`. All libraries that read Excel data can handle this and return a `DateTime` directly though.

Comment: Why are you converting the data to a string with `csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString()` then trying to parse it back? What does `csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen]` return? Is it perhaps a `DateTime` already?

Comment: BTW Excel isn't CSV. They're **completely** different formats. CSV is just a text file with separators and no types. Excel files are ZIP packages containing XML files, with string, number and date types. What do really have? Excel or CSV data?

Comment: Its CSV not excel

Comment: In that case you *have* to know the format in advance. Libraries like CsvHelper can read the file at once as long as you provide the correct culture, eg `en-US` or `en-GB`, to handle numbers and dates. You can avoid date issues if and only if the ISO8601 format is used. Using CsvReader you could produce a CsvDataReader and pass it directly to `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader)` to import data.

Comment: _"Its CSV not excel"_ in that case, you really need to talk to your data provider. You can give some slack about some portions of the format, but day/month _must_ be consistent. With a lot of effort, you could make _sophisticated guesses_ - but they would be just that: guesses.

Comment: The funny thing is I am able to import the data without any issues in windows10 laptop using visual studio, but the  error which I have given above is only appears when I run the same deployed  exe through windows scheduler in the Windows server 2012 machine

Comment: The issue after deployment could be the difference between your laptop's culture, and the server's culture. You can run into similar issues with decimals if your data is stored as `0.00` and the machine trying to read that data is expecting `0,00`

Comment: How to check my culture and server culture and make it consistent?

Comment: Go check your date and time settings in Windows. Should be under `Region` settings.

Comment: @SmartestVEGA `The funny thing is` it's not funny, it's fully expected. The behavior of both `Parse` and `ToString` are affected by the user's locale, which makes perfect sense since a user *does* expect local files to be in his/her locale. Both functions accept a `CultureInfo` to specify different cultures and settings. With a CSV though, the decimal settings will be different from one source to the next. That's why eg`CsvHelper` *requires* an explicit `CultureInfo` parameter instead of using the default. You'll have to modify your code to use an explicit `CultureInfo`

Comment: Thanks for the info, currently my server is down, will try this tomorrow  I also have a plan to keep a default cuture en-US in my app.settings   <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" /> Let me know your thoughts on the same?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, issue was because of culture info. Thanks to @Marius for bringing the point of Culture for my further analysis.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, issue was because of culture info. Thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos for bringing the point of Culture for my further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got sorted out when I changed the line

> DateTime.ParseExact(csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString() + ",531",
> "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm,fff",
> System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()

and included culture info

```
if (IsValidDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString()))
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(csvTable.Rows[i][Computer].ToString()
                       , **DateTime.ParseExact(csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString() + ",531", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()**);
                    }
                    else if (IsValidDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss", csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString()))
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(csvTable.Rows[i][Computer].ToString()
                                          , DateTime.ParseExact(csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString() + ",531", "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());


                    }
                    else if (IsValidDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy h:mm", csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString()))
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(csvTable.Rows[i][Computer].ToString()
                       , DateTime.ParseExact(csvTable.Rows[i][LastSeen].ToString() + ",531", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());

                    }
```